# Why payload is not parsed automatically?

Tags: node.js, hapi.js

*hapijs 17.2.0*

The route is

```
{
  method: 'POST',
  path: '/node/create',
  handler: function(request, h) {
    console.log(request.payload);
  },  
}
```

Post my data

```
curl -d '{"path": "dinos.456", "node": {"name": "velociraptor", "speed": 50, "force": 20}}' -X POST http://localhost:7001/node/create
```

And I see this result on the server

```
{ '{"path": "dinos.456", "node": {"name": "velociraptor", "speed": 50, "force": 20}}': '' }
```

Why is the payload not parsed into object automatically like it was in hapi v16? Maybe I miss some new option in the route?

Comment: maybe try setting `application/json` in request header?

Comment: see: https://github.com/hapijs/hapi/blob/cadf58952a5cd83673a6d1fd78f3eeda4e4d6817/API.md#route.options.payload.parse

Comment: @TuanAnhTran correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if not set

```
{
   method: 'POST',
   config: {
      validate: {
          payload: { /* joi schema */  }
      }
   }
}
```

then the payload will be a row buffer payload,
you need to format it by yourself